# Consume Attribute Ignored when Authorize Policy is applied to entire controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

We have been doing some security testing and have found an issue where if an incorrect Content-Type is posted then a 400 is returned instead of 415.

Now this only happens if I apply my Authorize attribute to the entire controller, and then set my Consumes Attribute on the post action. When the Authorize Attribute is applied to only an action along with the Consumes Attribute then this works just fine.

This works: Returns 415

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> APostActrion(MyModel model)
        {
            return View();
        }

}
```

This Doesn't: Returns 400

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
public class MyController : Controller
    {
            [HttpPost]                
            [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> APostActrion(MyModel model)
            {
                return View();
            }
    
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of my policy

```
options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", b =>
            {
                b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                b.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "MyRole");
                b.Requirements.Add(new OrganisationRequirement());
            });
```

Here is the AuthorizationHandler for OrganisationRequirement

```
public class OrganisationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<OrganisationRequirement>
    {
        private readonly StatelessServiceContext _context;

        public OrganisationHandler(StatelessServiceContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, OrganisationRequirement requirement)
        {
            if (CanRequest(context))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private bool CanRequest(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
        {
            string OrgId = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(_context.InitializationData, 0, _context.InitializationData.Length);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrgId))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && (c.Value == RoleNames.SysAdmin)))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value == RoleNames.Service)
                && context.User.HasClaim(c => (c.Type == CustomClaimTypes.OrgCode) && (c.Value == "system")))
            {
                return true;
            }

            if (context.User.HasClaim(c => (c.Type == CustomClaimTypes.OrgCode) && c.Value == OrgId))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share your policy code? I can't reproduce your problem. you can check [this](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/400-bad-request/) first

Comment: @Tisa Added some more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that if you have a [HTTPGet] Method that corresponds to your post method and don't annotate it with [HTTPGet], the post request gets directed to that get action.

**This causes an issue:**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{

        [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(MyModel model)
        {
            return View();
        }

}
```

**This resolves the issue:**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
        [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]            
        public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(MyModel model)
        {
            return View();
        }

}
```